# SQL query with a major NOT IN not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone know what's wrong with this query?

This works perfectly on its own:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM data WHERE site = '".$id."' 
AND disabled = '0' 
AND carvotes NOT LIKE '0' 
AND (time > ( now( ) - INTERVAL 14 DAY )) 
GROUP BY car ORDER BY carvotes DESC LIMIT 0 , 10) 
X order by time DESC
```

So does this:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE site = '".$id."' AND disabled = '0' GROUP BY car DESC ORDER BY time desc LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But combining them like this:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE site = '".$id."' AND disabled = '0' AND car NOT IN (SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM data WHERE site = '".$id."' 
    AND disabled = '0' 
    AND carvotes NOT LIKE '0' 
    AND (time > ( now( ) - INTERVAL 14 DAY )) 
    GROUP BY car ORDER BY carvotes DESC LIMIT 0 , 10) 
    X order by time DESC) GROUP BY car DESC ORDER BY time desc LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Gives errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run this query in phpmyadmin? What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Doesn't work. #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s). I am expecting to get all cars that's not in the first query (the NOT IN) part so that I can display them in a list below.

Comment: `.... car NOT IN (SELECT * FROM ......` - you should change the `SELECT *` to `SELECT car`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
$result = mysqli_query( $con,
                        "SELECT *
                         FROM data
                         WHERE site = '" . $id .
                         "' AND disabled = '0'
                            AND car NOT IN ( SELECT car
                                             FROM ( SELECT car,
                                                           carvotes
                                                    FROM data
                                                    WHERE site = '" . $id .
                                                    "' AND disabled = '0'
                                                       AND carvotes NOT LIKE '0'
                                                       AND ( time > ( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 14 DAY ) )
                                                    GROUP BY car
                                                    ORDER BY carvotes DESC
                                                    LIMIT 10 ) X
                                            )
                         GROUP BY car
                         ORDER BY time DESC
                         LIMIT 30" );
```

The main cause of your problem is that with `car NOT IN ( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *`... you are trying to compare each record's value of `car` with each row returned by your subquery.  `IN` requires you to have the same number of fields on both sides of the comparison.  By using `SELECT *` at both levels of the subquery you were ensuring that the right side of the comparison had however many fields are in `data` versus your single field on the left, which confused MySQL.

Since you are aiming to compare to a single field, namely `car`, our subquery has to select just the `car` field from its dataset.  Since the sort order of the subquery's results has no effect upon the `IN` comparison, and since our innermost query will be returning just `car`, I have removed the outer level of the subquery.

Beyond changing the first part of the subquery to `SELECT car`, the only other change that I have made to the subquery is to change `LIMIT 0, 10` to `LIMIT 10`.  The former means limit to the the `10` records that are offset by `0` from the first record.  This is useful if you want records `6` to `15`, but redundant for `1` to `10` as `LIMIT 10` has the same affect and is slightly simpler.  Ditto for `LIMIT 0, 30` at the end of your overall statement.

As for the main body of the statement, I have not made any attempt to specify what fields (or aggregate functions of those fields) should be returned since you have made no statement indicating what your requirements / preferences are.  If you are satisfied that `GROUP BY` has left you with a still valid set of values, then all the good, but if not then I recommend that you rewrite your Question to be specific about that detail.

By default, MySQL sorts the data subjected to a `GROUP BY` into ascending order, but if an `ORDER BY` clause is also present then it overrides the `GROUP BY`'s sort pattern.  As such, there is no benefit to specifying `DESC` after either of your `GROUP BY car` clauses, so I have removed it where it occurs.

Interesting Sidenote : You can override a `GROUP BY`'s sort by specifying `ORDER BY NULL`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Further Reading*

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html - on optimising your `ORDER BY` sorting

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html - on the `SELECT` statement's syntax - specifically the parts to do with `LIMIT`.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp - a simpler explanation of `LIMIT`

Comment: I'm in the middle of researching my explanation.  If, however, you are satisfied that this is indeed an Answer to your question and if you believe that it is the most helpful Answer of those available, then you can click on the tick near the top of the Answer to accept it.  Accepting an Answer rewards the answerer with 15 points and removes your Question from StackOverflow's list of unanswered Questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE site = '".$id."' AND disabled = '0' AND
      car NOT IN (SELECT * 
                  FROM (SELECT *
                        FROM data
                        WHERE site = '".$id."' AND
                              disabled = '0' AND
                              carvotes NOT LIKE '0'  AND
                              (time > ( now( ) - INTERVAL 14 DAY )) 
                        GROUP BY car
                        ORDER BY carvotes DESC
                        LIMIT 0 , 10
                       ) x 
                  ORDER BY time DESC
                 )
GROUP BY car DESC
ORDER BY time desc
LIMIT 0 , 30 ;
```

Several comments:

- Do not wrap integer constants in single quotes.  This can mislead people.  This can mislead optimizers.
- Do not use string functions on integers (such as `like`).  Same reason.
- `NOT IN` with subqueries is dangerous.  The construct does not handle `NULL` values the way you expect.  Use `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN` instead.
- When using subqueries, `ORDER BY` is almost never appropriate.
- Never use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  It is just wrong.  Happily, MySQL 5.7 has changed its defaults to reject this anti-pattern

So, a better way to write this query is something like this:

```
SELECT d.car, MAX(time) as time
FROM data d LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT d2.*
      FROM data d2
      WHERE d2.site = '".$id."' AND
            d2.disabled = 0 AND
            d2.carvotes NOT LIKE 0  AND
            (d2.time > ( now( ) - INTERVAL 14 DAY )) 
      GROUP BY d2.car
      ORDER BY carvotes DESC
      LIMIT 0 , 10
     ) car10
     ON d.car = car10.car
WHERE d.site = '".$id."' AND d.disabled = 0' AND
      car10.car IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY car DESC
ORDER BY MAX(time) desc
LIMIT 0 , 30 ;
```

Alternatively, use `SELECT *` and remove the `GROUP BY` in the outer query.